# How to initialize a wire[4:0] array in Verilog?

Tags: verilog

I want to initialize a 5-bit wire with a constant. How to do that in Verilog?

`wire [4:0] master_data_out = [1'b0, 1'b1, 1'b1, 1'b0, 1'b0];`

Comment: `wire [4:0] master_data_out` is a 5-bit wire.

Comment: 5 bit is fine. I reduced it from 64 to simplify for the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for

```
wire [4:0] master_data_out = 5'b01100;
```

or

```
wire [4:0] master_data_out = {1'b0, 1'b1, 1'b1, 1'b0, 1'b0};
```

BTW a simple web search would have yield that very basic concept mostlikely very quickly.